# Cannot get the list of running/current processes?

Tags: c#, session, process

I'm trying to get the list of running processes / sessions on my computer with Win7 using the following code, which is found in internet. However it doesn't work? I have not got any compile errors.

```
namespace CurrentProcessesLister
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          Process[] runningProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();
          var currentSessionID = Process.GetCurrentProcess().SessionId; 
          Process[] sameAsthisSession = (from c in runningProcesses where c.SessionId ==    currentSessionID select c).ToArray(); 

          foreach (var p in sameAsthisSession) 
          { 
              Trace.WriteLine(p.ProcessName); 
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ouch, please format your code to where it's readable. It makes answering your question a whole lot easier.

Comment: What is the output? (nice formatting btw)

Comment: Thanks alot. I just added <code> and </code> to the code text, but no idea about the formatting. how did you format it?

Comment: Hi OSH, there is no output in the console:(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> " there is no output in the console "

Then replace

```
Trace.WriteLine(p.ProcessName);
```

with

```
Console.WriteLine(p.ProcessName);
```

But if you then still don't see anything, it's time to start using the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using `Trace.WriteLine` to output the text.  This is used for program tracing and won't show up by default in the console.  Use `Console.WriteLine` instead.

```
  foreach (var p in sameAsthisSession) 
  { 
      Console.WriteLine(p.ProcessName); 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Quick and Dirty way...

```
  Process[] proc = Process.GetProcesses();
  foreach(Process theprocess in proc)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID: {1}", theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.Id);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To further expand on what the previous posts have mentioned, the trace output does indeed show up but you need to look in the debugger output window in Visual Studio. The code you originally posted does indeed list the processes under the Debug section in the output window.

> 'ConsoleApplication1.Program..' 'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe'
>   (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   devenv
>   winlogon
>   etc...

Comment: Sorry, I'm always using Ctrl+F5 instead of F5. I've seen it. How could I get a dynamic/live list of the running sessions?

Comment: Meaning you would like that list to be constantly updating instead of a run once? The easiest way would be to loop over the code on a periodic basis and work out some display method whether it be appending the new list to the end or doing something more involved.